# Accessing Docker container from another machine in an internal network

Tags: raspberry-pi, docker

I'm attempting to run a asp.net core application from a raspberry pi using docker, I think I have the main parts down. I have a repository on github that is a simplistic asp.net core project. I have setup an account on docker cloud which build everytime I push to my github repo.

I have docker pulled my repository onto my pi:
[image: screenshot of docker image being on pi]

I run the command:
`docker run -d -p 8080:80 joro550/radiusnet --network=host`
and I can see that it is running:
[image: image of docker image running]

But when I go to my pi's ip address on port 8080 then I get this:
[image: Connection refused screen shot]

When I've been searching around for this people have suggested adding these flags (which I have tried and come up with the same results:

- adding --network=host to the docker run command
- adding -it to the docker run command
- Adding Expose 80 into the docker file

I think at this point I'm at a bit of a lose as to how to access this thing.
The docker documentation does suggest running

```
`docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" myapp`
```

If I'm using windows 10 Nano containers, which I don't believe I'm using but when I run this command I get a resounding `<no value>`

Cutting it back to `docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" myapp` gives me a different ip address to my ips internal ip address, which I've tried on port 8080 and get the same result

Doing a curl on both addresses gives me the same result of connection refused:
[image: curl failing on ip address]

Here's my docker file for anyone interested:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY /src ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out -r linux-arm

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.0-runtime-stretch-arm32v7
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/src/RadiusNet.Web/out .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RadiusNet.Web.dll"]
```

If any more information is needed please ask, I'm pretty new to Docker so I just did a bit of a knowledge dump of my current situation.

Link to github project (if it's needed): https://github.com/joro550/RadiusNet

Any help - at this point will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73026/discussion-on-question-by-mark-davies-accessing-docker-container-from-another-ma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of remarks first

- in Dockerfile, "EXPOSE 80" is used by "docker run -P", "publish all"
- it's no use publishing a port the docker isn't servicing (eg. "-p 8000:80" when a service is running on port 5000

The listening ports are reported by "docker port", but they don't guarantee they will be serviced.

```
# docker run --name radiusnet -p 8001-8009:5000/tcp  radiusnet
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

# docker port radiusnet
5000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8001
```

The proof of the pudding ...

```
# wget -O /tmp/test.html  http://localhost:8001/
--2018-02-08 16:22:46--  http://localhost:8001/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8001... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

If this fails, the wrong ports have been published.

When started with "--network host", "docker port" may report nothing, while the docker is servicing nicely.  "lsof" can help.

```
# docker run --name radiusnet --network host  radiusnet
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000

# docker port radiusnet 

# ps -ef | grep dotnet
root       540 27973  0 16:46 pts/2    00:00:00 grep dotnet
root     32452 32437  7 16:37 ?        00:00:43 dotnet RadiusNet.Web.dll

# lsof -Pn -p 32452 | grep LISTEN
dotnet  32452 root  368u     IPv4     106845      0t0    TCP 127.0.0.1:5000 (LISTEN)
dotnet  32452 root  383u     IPv6     106854      0t0    TCP [::1]:5000 (LISTEN)

# wget -O /tmp/test.html  http://localhost:5000/       
--2018-02-08 16:56:27--  http://localhost:5000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/test.html’
```

All is well that ends well.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you more than once, thank you, from the bottom of my heart!!

Comment: You're welcome, it was an interesting exercise. But what was wrong with your setup?

Comment: I'll probably figure that out and add an answer of my own when I have time